# What bridge building game is this?

Tags: game-identification

I am not sure what game this is, but one of my friends [just sent me a funny .gif of it](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/044/2/8/bridge_by_intheflorsh-d76b15z.gif), and now I'm interested in playing it.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This game is called [Bridge Constructor](http://store.steampowered.com/app/250460/).

Answer (score 9):

This is a construction game called Bridge Constructor, available in the iOS App Store and Google Play. The point of the game is to make a sturdy enough bridge so that a variety of vehicles cross the bridge safely.